# how to configure asp.net mvc site to include a script in a particular publishing mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have setup three environments DEV, UAT and Live for our website built in Asp.net MVC. We need to add the google analytics script code (as below) on the live website only. How can we possibly configure this or any script so that when we publish the site in the release mode or another mode only then this script is added before the ending body tag of the _Layout view? thanks

```
<script>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the script in it's own file `GoogleAnalytics.js`.

Add it to a bundle with the [#if Preprocessor Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ga").Include(
#if(!DEBUG)
    "~/Scripts/GoogleAnalytics.js"),
#endif
   );
```

When you render the bundle, if it has no scripts nothing is rendered and no error messages.

Comment: @Eric, Just a quick question on this. When I publish the web project in Uat mode I want to stop this script for copying using preprocessor. For that i m trying something like `#if(!(DEBUG||UAT))
                "~/Scripts/google-analytics.js")
               #endif` but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the link I provided for how `#if` works.  The value you provide has nothing to do with the build type and is case sensitive (`UAT != Uat`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional compilation symbols. They are specific for build types. Right-click on your web project, go to properties, then go to build tab. There will be "Conditional compilation symbols" tab. Select the build type that should have analytics (Live). Add something like USER_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS there.

Now you can add "custom" analytics code via ifdef:

```
#if USER_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS
//code
#endif
```

This will not be in your view, but the code can modify something that changes your view rendering.